# Wood Floor Panel moved out of place and can’t move back, please help!

Tags: hardwood-floor, stuck

I was walking up the stairs and when I reached the top step my foot slid forward and wiped out. When I looked up, I saw that a panel had slightly moved, but when I tried to move the panel back into place it wouldn’t budge. How do I fix this?!? Please help![image][image]

Comment: The picture does not seem to describe the problem well enough for us to understand. Could you please add to the problem description to clarify? What does the picture show and where is the "panel" that shifted, in the picture?

Comment: I see it now, I was confused too.  A floor board has moved.  What looks like a piece of paper laying on the floor at first glance is actually a hole.  It’s odd, you must have had quite a fall.  I wonder which part moved the long board, or the short that’s is toward the wall?  (@JimmyFix-it look again with my added words)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What does the other end of this board look like? Does it butt up against a second board, or go all the way to the end of the flooring? (Another picture would be great.)

Comment: It looks like you've created a second "Trevor Arteaga" account. You should get these two accounts [merged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Did my second picture help with the perspective? @Tyson

Comment: So the short piece is pressed back under the wall.  It looks like it has a small lip.  I’d try just tapping the head of a nail into the lip so you can use it to get some leverage and move the board back up.  Getting it to stay in place is the hard part, but you could take off the 1/4 round at the wall and put a screw or nail at the wall, then put the 1/4 round back.  Taking the 1/4 off might also make it easier to move the board back in position.

Comment: Your floor likely has an expansion gap around the perimeter that's concealed by the trim and quarter round. If you're comfortable taking the quarter round and trim off, you should be able to pry the board back into place. A flooring jack would be a very helpful tool here, but it may not be worth the cost. In terms of securing the board in place, that expansion gap is there for a reason. I would consider putting some wood glue on the exposed tongue of the short board before sliding it back into place as an alternative to putting a screw or block in the expansion gap.